# Removing installed demo content wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I had the SCRN wordpress theme and by mistake pushed button Install Demo Content. Now one of the pages changed all the content. How can I remove it and make everything as it was?

Also in Pages I have 5 active and only 4 published. The 5th one is marked as Private but I can't see it (I suppose this one is my previous now hidden page)

Comment: Restore backup or remove DB and set new WP

Comment: This plugin will Resets the WordPress database back to it’s defaults.  plugin url  https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-reset/